# SQL. Sales Rank with join

Tags: mysql

I have tho tables: **orders** and **products**.
How to generate rank in MySQL 5.6?

In case when product values are the same rank has to be the same too. 
Below I need ranking by count

```
SELECT
  count(productpk), productpk,
  @prev := @curr,
  @curr := count(productpk),
  @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
FROM orders AS om
JOIN products AS p ON om.PK=p.p_order,
  (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) sel1
GROUP BY productpk ORDER BY count(productpk);
```

[image]

Valid result is (count -> rank):

- 2 -> 3
- 2 -> 3
- 4 -> 2
- 4 -> 2
- 6 -> 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do the trick.

```
SELECT
sq.productpk,
sq.cp,
@rank := IF(@prev = sq.cp, @rank, @rank + 1) AS rank,
@prev := sq.cp
FROM
(
    SELECT
    productpk,
    COUNT(productpk) AS cp
    FROM orders o
    JOIN products p ON o.PK = p.p_order
    GROUP BY productpk 
) sq
, (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rank := 0) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY sq.cp DESC
```

The order in the `SELECT` clause is important. When you do something like this first

```
@prev := @curr,
```

and then something like this

```
@rank := IF(@prev = @curr,...
```

it's pointless, because `@prev` will always be equal to `@curr`. `@curr` is in this case pointless, too, by the way.

You have to compare `@prev` with the current row in your `IF()` function. After that you assign the current row to `@prev`. When the next row is read, `@prev` still holds the value of the previous row.

And finally you have to put your grouping query in a subquery. One wouldn't think, that this is necessary, since the query is logically processed like

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. ORDER BY
6. SELECT

But MySQL doesn't do it like this, at least not when user defined variables are involved. See this simple test as proof:

```
root@localhost:playground > select a, @r:=@r+1 as r from bar, (select @r := 0) sq;
+------+------+
| a    | r    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    4 |
|    1 |    5 |
|    1 |    6 |
|    1 |    7 |
|    1 |    8 |
|    1 |    9 |
|    1 |   10 |
|    2 |   11 |
|    2 |   12 |
|    2 |   13 |
|    2 |   14 |
|    2 |   15 |
+------+------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > select a, @r:=@r+1 as r from bar, (select @r := 0) sq group by a;
+------+------+
| a    | r    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |   11 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using inner join with same result set

```
mysql> select DONATUR,COUNT(DISTINCT AREA) ,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank from funding,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r group by Donatur;               +---------+----------------------+------+
| DONATUR | COUNT(DISTINCT AREA) | rank |
+---------+----------------------+------+
| Mr.X    |                    3 |    1 |
| Mr.Y    |                    1 |    2 |
| Mr.Z    |                    2 |    3 |
| sss     |                    0 |    4 |
| wwww    |                    0 |    5 |
+---------+----------------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 SELECT x.DONATUR,x.area,if(x.rank>y.rank,y.rank,x.rank) AS rank FROM (select DONATUR,COUNT(DISTINCT AREA) as area ,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank from funding,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r group by Donatur) x LEFT JOIN  (select DONATUR,COUNT(DISTINCT AREA) as area ,@curRank2 := @curRank2 + 1 AS rank from funding,(SELECT @curRank2 := 0) r group by Donatur) y on y.rank<>x.rank and x.area=y.area;
+---------+------+------+
| DONATUR | area | rank |
+---------+------+------+
| Mr.X    |    3 |    1 |
| Mr.Y    |    1 |    2 |
| Mr.Z    |    2 |    3 |
| sss     |    0 |    4 |
| wwww    |    0 |    4 |
+---------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```